# Not able to access stepExecutionContext value in writer

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning

I am setting the stepExecutionContext value in my partitioner and trying to get it in Writer.

But i could not able to access it.

The writer is step scoped.

Could any one help me how to get the step execution context values in writer?

Thanks

Shankar

Comment: What have you tried/errortrace? How is your writer configuration? Normally you can get an `ExecutionContext` value by setting a property like `<property name="something" value="#{stepExecutionContext['something']}"/>` in your writer configuration.

Comment: Actually i forgot to have the property in my partitioner. i was just setting the value in ExecutionContext without property. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement StepExecutionListener in writer to get stepExecution in writer

```
public class ExampleWriter implements ItemWriter<T>,StepExecutionListener {
private JobExecution jobExecution;

@Override
public void write(List<? extends T> items) {
String executionContextValue=jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get("KEY");
System.out.println("ExecutionContextValue is:"+executionContextValue);
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.jobExecution=  stepExecution.getJobExecution();
}
```

}

If needed register this class as a listener  in xml configuration

```
<listener>ExampleWriter</listener>
```